# pandas: retain hour while setting a constant for date, minutes

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I want to create a new column of datetime by setting a constant for the year, month, day, and minutes, seconds, retaining only the

```
import pandas as pd
td = pd.DataFrame(['2015-01-01 09:03:00', '2015-01-11 15:47:00', 
            '2015-01-11 16:47:00', '2015-01-11 01:47:00', '2016-01-11 01:47:00'], columns=['datetime'])
td['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(td['datetime'])


    datetime
0   2015-01-01 09:03:00
1   2015-01-11 15:47:00
2   2015-01-11 16:47:00
3   2015-01-11 01:47:00
4   2016-01-11 01:47:00
```

The result should look like this.

```
    datetime
0   1900-01-01 09:00:00
1   1900-01-01 15:00:00
2   1900-01-01 16:00:00
3   1900-01-01 01:00:00
4   1900-01-01 01:00:00
```

How can I code this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `pd.to_timedelta`

```
pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(td.datetime.dt.hour, unit='H')

0   1900-01-01 09:00:00
1   1900-01-01 15:00:00
2   1900-01-01 16:00:00
3   1900-01-01 01:00:00
4   1900-01-01 01:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
td['datetime'].apply(lambda x: datetime(1900, 1, 1) + timedelta(hours=x.hour))

0   1900-01-01 09:00:00
1   1900-01-01 15:00:00
2   1900-01-01 16:00:00
3   1900-01-01 01:00:00
4   1900-01-01 01:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```